# getSelectedItem from Spinner inside custom ListView element

Tags: java, android, listview, spinner

I googled alot for this with no result. I have a custom ListView, every element has few TextViews and 3 Spinners and button. When I set values on spinners and press a button I want to get selcted values from those spinners and send them to a server. Everything works fine for list elements from top to the last visible element but on items that are not visible or visible in half 2 bad things happen.

If I change value on spinner, press button to save, 2 things happen depedning on which element I work on:

1. If element was half, or a little visible on activity load and I do those steps on it the value that is passed is the value that was set before I changed it.
2. If element wasn't visible at all and I do steps on it app crashes with NullPointerException linking the error to the declaration of a Spinner.

Code:

Adapter:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

            StudentList students = studentList.get(position);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_list, null);

            TextView id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_id);
            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_name);
            TextView surname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_surname);
            Spinner t1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.list_t1);
            Spinner t2 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.list_t2);
            Spinner t3 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.list_t3);
            TextView final = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_final);
            Button save = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.save);

            id.setText(students.getId());
            name.setText(students.getName());
            surname.setText(students.getSurname());
            final.setText(students.getFinal());

            for (int i=0;i<t1.getCount();i++){
                if (t1.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(students.getT1())){
                    t1.setSelection(i);
                }
            }
            for (int i=0;i<t2.getCount();i++) {
                if (t2.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(students.getT2())) {
                    t2.setSelection(i);
                }
            }

            for (int i=0;i<t3.getCount();i++){
                if (t3.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(students.getT3())){
                    t3.setSelection(i);
                }
            }

            if(t1.getSelectedItemPosition() > 1){
                t2.setEnabled(false);
                t3.setEnabled(false);
            } else if (t2.getSelectedItemPosition() > 1){
                t3.setEnabled(false);
            }

            save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);
                }
            });        



            if(studentList.get(position).getProtokol().equals("open")){

            } else {
                t1.setEnabled(false);
                t2.setEnabled(false);
                t3.setEnabled(false);
                save.setEnabled(false);
            }


            return view;
        }
```

onCreate:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                long viewId = view.getId();

                Spinner t1 = (Spinner) parent.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.lista_termin1);//There the app crashes if I do things I described above
                Spinner t2 = (Spinner) parent.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.lista_termin2);
                Spinner t3 = (Spinner) parent.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.lista_termin3);  

                if (viewId == R.id.save) {
                        String t1Itemn = t1.getSelectedItem());
                        String t2Itemn = t2.getSelectedItem());
                        String t3Itemn = t3.getSelectedItem());
                        //Code that sends those string to the server based on urlConnection - works perfectly fine)
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was googling for 2 days and finally decided to post here, but 1h later I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23368314/listview-getchildat-giving-nullpointer-for-not-visible-elements-android). Changed all spinners like this:

```
Spinner t1 = (Spinner) parent.getChildAt(position-parent.parent.getFirstVisiblePosition()).findViewById(R.id.lista_termin1);
```